# Print updated value before it should update

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, automatic-ref-counting

Here's a short code

```rust
use std::{thread, time::{Duration}, sync::{Arc, Mutex}};

fn main() {
    let num = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0u8));
    let clone = num.clone();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            println!("{:?};", *num.lock().unwrap()); // always prints 0
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
            *num.lock().unwrap() = 0;
            println!("{:?};", *num.lock().unwrap()); // always prints 0
        }
    });

    listen(clone);
}

fn listen(num: Arc<Mutex<u8>>) {
    rdev::listen(move |event| {
        match event.event_type {
            rdev::EventType::KeyPress(_) => {
                *num.lock().unwrap() += 1;
            },
            _ => {},
        }
    }).unwrap();
}
```

All it should do is just counting how many times the users pressed any key on a keyboard. But this code is doesn't work.

I added 2 `println!` statements - before the value is updated and after that. And I assume to get a real value in the first statement and `0` in the second one. But for some reason both `println!` print a zero.

Why so and how can I avoid it?

---

The code does work if I don't reset value to a zero. But I have to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you leave no time between the `num` read and write. So it writes the `num` value and immediatly read from it.

You probably want to add an extra delay statement:

```rust
loop {
    println!("{:?};", *num.lock().unwrap());
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    *num.lock().unwrap() = 0;
    println!("{:?};", *num.lock().unwrap());
    //this delay will allow the other thread to modify the num before the read happens.
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I thought it was something about mutex or `ARC` or multithreading, but in the end it was only my inattention. By the way, more correct way would by just replacing `sleep` to the end of the loop